# Removing guest account from Ubuntu 12.04 caused Ubuntu to go to terminal on startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, guest-account

I have used [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-tiphow-to-disable-guest-account-in-ubuntu-12-04precise.html) tutorial to disable guest account on Ubuntu 12.04. The change was basically adding this line

```
allow-guest=false
```

to the file

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

And the result was that on startup, lightdm failed, and the system was going to a terminal on startup rather than the typical lightdm user interface.

This was totally reversible, so I went to that file and removed that line, and everything went back to normal. But guest account is still there.

What is happening? And why does that line mess my lightdm?

Thank you.

EDIT: My current lightdm.conf is as follows:

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=samer
autologin-user-timeout=0
autologin-session=lightdm-autologin
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

This article from [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/117994/how-to-disable-ubuntus-guest-session-account/) uses the same method you tried, so not sure what specifically happened with you. Might want to check your file for any sneaky characters you might have missed. Maybe post the content of said file.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but the suggestion you provided is for Ubuntu 8.10. There's nothing called "gdm" anymore on Ubuntu 12, it's called now lightdm. I tried to replace the name but it didn't work too. Check the edit in my post.